# Dual monitors: one monitor starts blinking and after a while  turns black

Tags: 11.04, configuration, multiple-monitors, gnome

I am using dual monitors in Ubuntu 11 with classical interface (Not Unity). I am using two monitors. The system can detect and automatically configure the monitors correctly. The problem is that after some time, one monitor will start blinking and after a while it will turn black. Does any one know that it is the problem of my hardware or the problem of Ubuntu system? Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Anand

Comment: Could you tell us some more about your hardware? eg. graphics card

Comment: I am sorry, I don't know how I can see my graphic card. It is this model: http://www.amazon.com/Lenovo-7269D7U-Thinkcentre-E7500-320GB/dp/tech-data/B002XHD6NQ/ref=de_a_smtd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would tip it is a hardware problem. Once I had very similar behavior with DisplayPort->DVI adapter: It worked perfectly fine for approx 5 minutes and then the screen went black.

What type of connectivity do you use?

My personal experience with DisplayPort->DVI adapters is very bad: 2 out of 3 had problems so far.

Comment: Dear Baranauskas, Exactly, the second adapter is DisplayPort->DVI adapter. So I should change this adapter?

Comment: Well, it MIGHT be that the new adapter will solve the problem, however it is not guaranteed. My current adapter which works so far is this one: http://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B001F0QUWG/ If you (or someone you know) have other computer with DisplayPort, I recommend connecting your DisplayPort->DVI adapter there and see if the problems occur.

Comment: Okay. I will try to find anther adapter... Thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: Thanks Baranauskas, after changing another adapter, my problem solves. I hope it can last long time.Thank you very much!

Comment: After two days with the new adapter, my system works well. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've had problem once in while and a workaround I've used is to switch the affected monitor off for a few seconds. When you turn it back on the problem appears be rectified.