# DisplayPort with Intel integrated graphics

Tags: 11.04, xorg, intel-graphics

I have a HP Compaq 6000 Pro small form factor which has a DisplayPort output and Ubuntu 11.04 installed. The machine has integrated Intel graphics.

I am trying to connect the machine to a monitor with displayport to displayport to use as a second monitor.

When booting, the screen recognizes the machine and BIOS startup is displayed, however when Ubuntu loads the screen goes black and the monitor goes into sleep mode.

The screen cannot be detected from System > Preferences > Monitors. Unfortunately the HP Compaq 6000 Pro only has VGA and DisplayPort - it doesn't have DVI since it is a small form factor. I don't have a DisplayPort>DVI Adapter either, but this shouldn't make a difference, it would appear to be an intel/xorg problem with recognizing the DisplayPort device.

Could anybody suggest a way to debug this problem? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug with the intel driver that seems to be a similar issue but instead of the DVI port it's the s-video ports and in some cases it has been the VGA out as well.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/763688

If you haven't marked it as effecting you, please do so.

This particular bug appears to be xserver-xorg-video-intel which also can be seen in Kubuntu and even other distros that use this same driver (I have seen it in Fedora 15 as well).

Answer (score 0):

Do you use DisplayPort->DVI adapter? My personal experience shows that they are unreliable. See: [Dual monitors: one monitor starts blinking and after a while  turns black](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42426/)

Comment: Hello Vilmantas!

Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately the HP Compaq 6000 Pro only has VGA and DisplayPort - it doesn't have DVI since it is a small form factor.

I don't have a DisplayPort>DVI Adapter either, but this shouldn't make a difference, it would appear to be an intel/xorg problem with recognising the DisplayPort device.

Thank you for your comment though!

Edit - the cable I'm using is DisplayPort (Male) to DisplayPort (Male), which works OK with Windows but not Linux.

Comment: Good, at least you know the hardware is not the problem.